# Delete directory with all files in it using gradle task

Tags: gradle

In my project's root I have a directory as follows:

```
build/exploded-project/WEB-INF/classes
```

I want to delete all the files in the classes directory using a gradle task. I tried the of the following combinations but none of them worked:

```
task deleteBuild(type: Delete) {
    project.delete 'build/exploded-project/WEB-INF/classes/'
}

task deleteBuild(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build/exploded-project/WEB-INF/classes/'
}

task deleteBuild(type: Delete) {
    delete '$rootProject.projectDir/build/exploded-project/WEB-INF/classes/'
}

task deleteBuild(type: Delete) {
    delete fileTree('build/exploded-project/WEB-INF/classes').matching {
        include '**/*.class'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested a better approach is to use Gradle Variables.

Try:

```java
task deleteBuild(type: Delete) {
    delete "$buildDir/exploded-project/WEB-INF/classes/"
}
```

Pay attention to replace the single quote with the double one.

Regards,

S.

Answer (score 1):

Your second variant is correct and works fine here.
Though I'd recommend not hardcoding the path.
Use `$buildDir` instead of `build`, or if the path is the output path of another task use the respective property of that task.

If it doesn't work for you, run with `-i` or `-d` to get more information about what is going on and possibly going wrong.

Comment: I ran it with -i and it reported "Task ':deleteFiles' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs." - But I refreshed my gradle project from within IntelliJ. So what are these "outputs" it's complaining about?

Comment: Nah, that's ok. A Gradle task should define which tasks and properties form its inputs and what files form its output. Then Gradle can pretty good decide whether a task is up-to-date or needs to be executed. In case of a delete task there is of course not output file and so it probably always is out-of-date.